# R - Get string after whitespace

Tags: r, regex

I have a stats file that has the following format.

```
---------- Begin Simulation Statistics ----------
simSeconds                                   0.000500                       # Number of seconds simulated (Second)
simTicks                                    500000000                       # Number of ticks simulated (Tick)
finalTick                                   500000000                       # Number of ticks from beginning of simulation (restored from checkpoints and never reset) (Tick)
simFreq                                  1000000000000                       # The number of ticks per simulated second ((Tick/Second))
hostSeconds                                      7.36                       # Real time elapsed on the host (Second)
hostTickRate                                 67905191                       # The number of ticks simulated per host second (ticks/s) ((Tick/Second))
hostMemory                                     658020                       # Number of bytes of host memory used (Byte)
simInsts                                       956628                       # Number of instructions simulated (Count)
simOps                                        1634485                       # Number of ops (including micro ops) simulated (Count)
hostInstRate                                   129917                       # Simulator instruction rate (inst/s) ((Count/Second))
hostOpRate                                     221975                       # Simulator op (including micro ops) rate (op/s) ((Count/Second))
system.clk_domain.clock                          1000                       # Clock period in ticks (Tick)
system.cpu.numCycles                          1000001                       # Number of cpu cycles simulated (Cycle)
system.cpu.numWorkItemsStarted                      0                       # Number of work items this cpu started (Count)
system.cpu.numWorkItemsCompleted                    0                       # Number of work items this cpu completed (Count)
system.cpu.instsAdded                         1824678                       # Number of instructions added to the IQ (excludes non-spec) (Count)
system.cpu.nonSpecInstsAdded                       85                       # Number of non-speculative instructions added to the IQ (Count)
system.cpu.instsIssued                        1774419                       # Number of instructions issued (Count)
system.cpu.squashedInstsIssued                    817                       # Number of squashed instructions issued (Count)
system.cpu.squashedInstsExamined               190251                       # Number of squashed instructions iterated over during squash; mainly for profiling (Count)
system.cpu.squashedOperandsExamined            226242                       # Number of squashed operands that are examined and possibly removed from graph (Count)
system.cpu.squashedNonSpecRemoved                  37                       # Number of squashed non-spec instructions that were removed (Count)
system.cpu.numIssuedDist::samples              914073                       # Number of insts issued each cycle
system.cpu.numIssuedDist::mean               1.941222                       # Number of insts issued each cycle
system.cpu.numIssuedDist::stdev              2.095850                       # Number of insts issued each cycle
system.cpu.numIssuedDist::underflows                0      0.00%      0.00% # Number of insts issued each cycle
system.cpu.numIssuedDist::0                    403267     44.12%     44.12% # Number of insts issued each cycle
system.cpu.numIssuedDist::1                     63660      6.96%     51.08% # Number of insts issued each cycle"
```

I read it line by line in a while loop. For each line, I want to use str_extract to get the name of each stat and then the first value.

For the former I use, `str_extract(line, "(\\S+)")`. For the latter I tried `str_extract(line, "\\s+(\\S+)")`, but I get the whitespace before the value. How can I change it to not include that part?

Also, is there a more "elegant" way of achieving the same thing?

Comment: I am getting a Syntax error in regexp pattern.

Comment: Use a lookbehind, `str_extract(test3, "(?<=\\s)\\S+")`.

Comment: Yeah. `Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX, context=\`(?<\s)\S+\`)
`

Comment: Sorry, there must be a `=`. Actually, you may use many other approaches here.

Comment: why not read it in like normal rectangular data? `read.table('stats.txt', skip = 1, fill = TRUE, col.names = c('stat', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3'))`

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: Or `trimws`, for **trim *w*hite *s*pace**: `trimws(str_extract(line, "\\s+(\\S+)"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```r
str_extract(test3, "(?<!\\S|^)\\S+")
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/r6mFHF/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```r
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
```

Comment: Instead of `(?<!\\S|^)` isn't it more simple to write `(?<=\\s)` ?

Comment: Correct. But still works.